# Does HTTP as a protocol include any mechanism for guaranteeing information?

Tags: networking, http, tcp

I asked this question on networkengineering.stackexchange, without realizing that any protocols on top of TCP were off topic (i.e. that only OSI layers 4 and lower are on topic there).

The question is this:

> Since HTTP is implemented on top of TCP, and TCP is lossless, does
>   HTTP include any kind of information for packet assembly?
>
> I imagine that once an HTTP request is complete that you can just
>   assume that the HTTP information is complete (since the entire
>   sequence of TCP packets used to transport HTTP is guaranteed to be
>   ordered and completed).
>
> Is this assumption correct?

A quick google search shows me that OSI layer 4 deals specifically with end-to-end connections and reliability, which leads me to understand that HTTP packets do NOT require any means of checking integrity as they are re-assembled. i.e. that at the end of a network transmission, an HTTP packet will be fully and correctly assembled if the TCP session completed without errors.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, HTTP/1.x does not include any packet reassembly/redelivery mechanism. It expects the transport layer (typically TCP or QUIC) to provide it, as seen in [RFC 7230, section 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6):

> **6. Connection Management**
>
> HTTP messaging is independent of the underlying transport- or
> session-layer connection protocol(s).  HTTP only presumes a reliable
> transport with in-order delivery of requests and the corresponding
> in-order delivery of responses.

---

That said, HTTP/1.x *does* include optional mechanisms for identifying when a response is **complete**. This is needed because HTTP/1.x supports connection reuse, and the same underlying TCP connection may be used for multiple request/response pairs. (And of course TCP has no notion of separate messages.)

Cients using "Connection: close" (default in HTTP/1.0) can simply assume that a cleanly-closed TCP connection indicates end-of-response. However, clients using "Connection: keep-alive" (default in HTTP/1.1) expect the response to have either

1. a "Content-Length:" header if the response length is definite and known, or
2. a zero-length chunk if the response is of indefinite length and uses "Transfer-Encoding: chunked".

---

The same is still true of HTTP/2 over TCP, and even HTTP over QUIC.